# Checking presence of an element in subset of a mongodb array

Tags: mongodb, data-analysis

I need to select the documents in the mongodb database in which a condition has to be met which is described below.

I have an array in each of the document which looks something like this:

Payload.Signal.value[0.0,0.1,2.0,3.0,3.2,.......]

I need to select only the documents in the database where a certain value should be present at-least once in the subset of the above array. The desired subset of the array is from 300th position (if it exists) to the end of the array.

I need to write a mongodb query where the document needs to be selected if the desired value is present in the slice of the array from 300th position to the end of the array.

I looked into $slice operator documentation but it doesn't have any provision to specify the end of the array when the end position is unknown.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more information with an example? I couldn't get you.

Comment: I have to select the documents in the database where for e.g. if the desired value is 30.0, then all the documents where the value 30.0 is at-least present once in the slice (or the subset) of the array payload.signal.value (from position index 300 to end of the array) should be selected and count should be returned of no of such documents matching this condition.